# Youtube XML search API provides description of the video without any highlight

Tags: youtube-api

I am using youtube ATOM xml to retrieve search results related to search terms -

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&max-results=10&q=obscure+search+terms&safeSearch=moderate&oi=spell&start-index=1&spell=1
```

The XML has description for each video but the description does not have any keyword highlighting. For example, if I search for 'soccer', I expect all the word that has 'soccer' in it, to be highlighted by using some tag on the returned XML. Is there any way to get it ?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's not. What does "highlighting" even mean in this context--there's no standard way of representing "highlighting" in XML, so if you're talking about a <b> tag around the search term, that only would be a viable solution for developers who plan on displaying the result in a HTML page. If they did anything else with the result, like display it in a native mobile app, the <b> would be meaningless noise.

In the past, there have been a few instances where search results were being returned with <b> tags around the search terms, but those were bugs, and they all should have been resolved.

Comment: Yes by highlighting, I meant high light the search term within some kind of a tag. It may not be <b> tag alone, but can be anything like <kw> search term </kw> where kw stands for key word. Then developer have option to replace <kw> by <b> tag or span tag with css class on it which then can be rendered anywhere accordingly.

Comment: That's not going to happen. The idea is that the API responses should be ready for display in any application, and asking folks to check for <kw> tags and manipulate the string based on their presence is not in keeping with the API's philosophy.